# Position von "möge"

Tags: difference, word-order

Manchmal merke ich mir, dass das Wort "möge" nicht immer an die erste Position gestellt wird, sondern an die zweite.
Gibt es hier einen Unterschied?

1. Möge die Freude in diesem Hause nie versiegen!
2. Diese Legende möge unser Buch beschließen.

Comment: Während Beispiel 1 eine normale Optativ-Konstruktion darstellt, ist Beispiel 2 nicht ganz auf dem Punkt. Es könnte auch einen einfachen Konjunktiv darstellen, weil der Autor es ja komplett in der Hand hat. Vermutlich ist das eine Höflichkeitsfloskel im vergleichbar mit *Dürfte ich eine Frage stellen?*. Es mutet verstaubt an und ich würde von Nachahmung abraten.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In der deutschen Sprache ist die Wortreihenfolge sehr frei und kann -beinahe nach Belieben- umgestellt werden, um einzelne Teile des Satzes zu betonen.

Beispielsweise sind alle diese Satzstellungen vollkommen in Ordnung:

1. Möge die Freude in diesem Hause nie versiegen!
2. Die Freude in diesem Hause möge nie versiegen!
3. Die Freude möge in diesem Hause nie versiegen!
4. In diesem Hause möge die Freude nie versiegen!
5. Möge in diesem Hause die Freude nie versiegen!

Ungewöhnlich / altmodisch aber immer noch korrekt wäre z.B.:

5. Nie versiegen möge die Freude in diesem Hause!

Also: NEIN, inhaltlich gibt es keinen Unterschied, man stellt nur die Sache, die  man für die wichtigste im Satz hält, an den Anfang desselben.

Comment: Völlig frei ist die Position von *möge* allerdings nicht, sondern es sind nur Positionen 1 und 2 möglich, wie dem Fragesteller bereits aufgefallen ist. Das ist nicht immer ganz offensichtlich, weil beim 1. Satzglied weitere Attribute stehen können und es daher mehrteilig ausfallen kann.

Comment: Insbesondere sind Varianten 2 und 3-5 hier nicht identisch. In 2 modifiziert "in diesem Hause" das Subjekt "die Freude", in 3-5 den ganzen Satz. Variante 1 ist nicht eindeutig und kann auf beide Arten interpretiert werden.

Answer (score 1):

Einen entscheidenden morphologischen Unterschied sehe ich dort ebenfalls nicht, allerdings syntaktische und auch pragmatische. Den **ersten Satz** sehe ich eher als einen Wunschsatz geäußert gegenüber einem anwesenden Empfänger, z.B. bei einer Festrede. Man vergleiche dazu den berühmten Satz '*Möge die Macht mit dir sein*' aus Star Wars. In Wunschsätzen kann ein Verb die Erststellung einnehmen: Wäre er nur schon hier!

Wenn es sich um ein Motto handelt, das als Sinnspruch über einer Eingangstür oder an der Fassade angebracht ist, richtet es sich an potentielle Nutznießer dieses Wunsches oder an Unbeteiligte, die zur Kenntnis nehmen können, dass das Haus unter diesem Segenswunsch steht. Diese Lesart ähnelt der des **zweiten Satz**es:

Es handelt sich um einen floskelhaften Gebrauch von '*möge*', mit welchem der auktoriale 'Erzähler' eines narrativen Textes oder einer Zusammenstellung narrativer Texte sich an den Leser / Zuhörer wendet, um den Leser mit einer gewissen Sanftheit seelisch darauf einzustimmen, dass nun das Ende der Erzählung(en) erreicht ist. **Eine Voranstellung von '*möge*' ist hier nicht möglich**. Eine vergleichbare Floskel ist *damit mag es nun sein Bewenden haben* = 'mehr ist dazu von meiner Seite nicht zu erwarten.'